# Where to set username/password for BASIC authentication in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, http-basic-authentication

I have a .net web app running on iis7 (windows 2008) and want to add some simple protection to it.

I've managed to set up BASIC authentication, but cant work out where I set the username/passwords that are allowed to access the resource

Comment: Exactly [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5373497/465053) on stackoverflow. I'm sure it will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box these would need to be Windows 2008 accounts.

If you wanted to use a custom store (SQL Server, Membership Service) then you'd need to write your own Basic Authentication module:

> [Developing a Module Using .NET](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/170/developing-a-module-using-net/)